# in github, can I clone/merge branch online?

Tags: github

I want to clone/merge branch for my git repository inside github, for example merge updates in `draft` branch to `gh-pages` for publish.

And in some cases, I don't have access to command line for git command.

Is it possible to achieve this online ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can merge branches in GitHub using a Pull Request as long as the merge doesn't create any conflicts.

**To merge a pull request on GitHub:**

1. Create a Pull Request to merge the `draft` branch into the
   `gh-pages` branch.
2. If it can be merged online, you'll see ***This pull request can be automatically merged***. and a `Merge pull
   request` button.
3. Click the button and you'll have a chance to `Cancel` the merge or add a commit message and `Confirm Merge`.
4. If you choose to `Confirm Merge`, the Pull Request will automatically close.

For more information, visit [Github's Merging a Pull Request Help page](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request).

Comment: Yes, great, I never thought it could be used for own branch.